# How to keep state in Junit 5 parameterized test?

Tags: java, junit, junit5

Is it possible to keep the changes made to a variable across executions of a parameterized test?

I have a simple calendar that stores events added to it:

```
class MyCalendar {

    private final List<int[]> events;

    public MyCalendar() {
        events = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public boolean book(int start, int end) {
        // some validation logic here
        events.add(new int[]{start, end});
        return true;
    }
}
```

in order to test that it works on subsequent calls, I need to call it several times in the tests:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class MyCalendarTest {

    private MyCalendar myCalendar = new MyCalendar();

    @Test
    void givenExample1() {
        myCalendar = new MyCalendar();
        assertTrue(myCalendar.book(10, 20));
        assertFalse(myCalendar.book(15, 25));
        assertTrue(myCalendar.book(20, 30));
    }

}
```

this works fine. However, I can't make it work with parameterized tests instead:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.CsvSource;

class MyCalendarTest {

    private MyCalendar myCalendar = new MyCalendar();

    @ParameterizedTest
    @CsvSource(value = {"10,20,true", "15,25,false", "20,30,true"})
    void givenExample2(int start, int end, boolean expected) {
        assertEquals(expected, myCalendar.book(start, end));
    }

}
```

the problem is that `myCalendar` is re-initialized after each test execution, so the previously added events are lost. Of course, moving the initialization inside the test method doesn't help either.

Is this possible at all?

Comment: Every test method should be self contained.  The first way you wrote your test is correct -- and best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, all parameterised tests run in isolation. As a result, you cannot acces the previous values in parameterised tests. Also, the execution order of parameterised tests can be random based on number of free theads and parallel processing.

One of the solution for your use case would be to store the data in an array. Then just loop through that array and call your desired function. This way you can test your function in subsequent manner and you will have a control over the order of values.